# Gmaps Open multiple Info Windows from MarkerClusters

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

Ok what i have is a Google map that i have on my site showing upwards of 2000+ markers with Marker clustering.

I would like to Add info windows for the markers. but i have a few markers at the exact same point that is in a cluster.

Is there a way to show multiple info windows on that cluster appended to each other. or if i zoom in past clustering i still have multiple markers layered on each other. i need to show info windows for each of them[image]

```
%div{:style => "padding: 6px; order-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: #ccc #ccc #999 #ccc; -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px; -moz-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px; box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.1) 0 2px 5px;"}
      #map{:style => "width: 100%; height: 500px;"}
    :javascript
      handler = Gmaps.build('Google', { markers: { clusterer: {gridSize: 50, maxZoom: 50} } });
      handler.buildMap({ provider: { disableDefaultUI: true }, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
          markers = handler.addMarkers(#{raw @hash.to_json});
          handler.getMap().setZoom(4);
          handler.map.centerOn([40.8777416,-97.3809789]);
      });
```

more info

```
@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(post) do |load, marker|
  olat, olng = Location.to_coords(load.origin)
  marker.lat olng
  marker.lng olat
  marker.infowindow 'testing info windows'
end
```

**Here is a working example of kinda what i want... but not sure how to implement it into my coding:**

http://www.concepteur-internet.fr/test_carto1.php

Tring to figure out how to incorporate the following code into my javascript

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerClusterer, 'clusterclick', function(cluster){

            var content ='';
             var clickedMarkers = cluster.getMarkers();

             for (var i = 0; i < clickedMarkers.length; i++) {
             if(i==0){
             var var_pos = clickedMarkers[i];

             }
            var html = clickedMarkers[i].html;
            content +=html;
            }

             infowindow.setContent(content);
             infowindow.open(map,var_pos);
             bulle=1;
            });




            }
        });
```

Comment: you cant attach an infowindow to a cluster, what about randomizing the coordinates so they'll be separate markers?

Comment: yeah there is... here is an example just not sure how to implement it... http://www.concepteur-internet.fr/test_carto1.php

Comment: they are not using a standard cluster, seems to be a solution of theirs